# AWS Glue - Delete rows from SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, aws-glue

I am creating an AWS Glue job which uses JDBC to connect to SQL Server. Intention of this job is to insert the data into SQL Server after some logic. I need to first delete the existing rows from the target SQL Server table and then insert the data from AWS Glue job into that table.

I checked many articles but I could not find the details of deleting/truncating the existing rows in SQL Server.

Can you please let me know if there are any options for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to find an option to delete specific rows from the table through AWS Glue. Please find the below link where the option to truncate the existing table is available.

https://commenting.awsblogs.com/embed.html?disqus_shortname=aws-big-data-blog&disqus_identifier=4912&disqus_title=Use+AWS+Glue+to+run+ETL+jobs+against+non-native+JDBC+data+sources&disqus_url=https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-aws-glue-to-run-etl-jobs-against-non-native-jdbc-data-sources/#comment-4891498420

Answer (score 0):

The sort of delete action you are looking for is not available. The alternative would be to use python modules to achieve the actions that you want. Running this for each row might be slow. You can experiment with different patterns to see which one gives you the best performance. An Example would be , loading the records to delete to a staging table and running a sql command to do a delete on the target table using rows in the temp staging table. That would work out to be better in case of huge loads. The sql command can be run via a python dB module that is pure python like pypyodbc.

Answer (score 0):

Please **enable bookmark** for the job, which holds the last processed data and appends any new data that got generated on source.